# Flex 4 VGroup,Hgroup Scroll

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, scrollbar

Hi Guys I have a problem with vertical scroll bar, please help me, my component structure is as below, Iam working on flex4

```
<HGROUP>
   <VGROUP>
       <LABEL/>
        <ADVANCEDDATAGRID/>
   </VGROUP>
   <CANVAS/>
</HGROUP>
```

heights are given to 100%, I have large data in datagrid, which is creating vertical scrollbar in the middle of the component,I neeed the scrollbar to the parent component that is HGROUP, can anybody help me

Answer (score 0):

Put your component inside a scroller tag and set the vertical scroll policy of advancedatagrid to off.

```
<s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%" >
                <s:HGroup height="100%">                    
                    <s:VGroup height="100%">
                        <s:Label/>
                        <mx:AdvancedDataGrid width="100%" height="100%" verticalScrollPolicy="off"/>
                    </s:VGroup>
                    <mx:Canvas/>
                </s:HGroup>
            </s:Scroller>
```